# EFCore data migrations throws me an error when add the second migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

When I create a Migration on my asp.net core 3.1 application with efcore, it works fine.

```
dotnet-ef migrations add Dev001 --project ..\Infrastructure\LetzIt.SqlServerDbService\LetzIt.SqlServerDbService.csproj --startup-project .\LetzIt.WebApi\LetzIt.WebApi.csproj
```

If I just add a new Domain class (entity) and configure on my modelconfiguration builder and run the command:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add Dev002 --project ..\Infrastructure\LetzIt.SqlServerDbService\LetzIt.SqlServerDbService.csproj --startup-project .\LetzIt.WebApi\LetzIt.WebApi.csproj
```

The output gives me this error:

[image]

ps: sorry for the image, but the error here was too ugly to understand.
The main lines are:

> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.

and

> Failed to compare two elements in the array.

I searched a lot about this and nothing appears to me. I'm not using any SORT by myself. There is no OrderBy in my code anymore.

Here comes an example of entity configuration:

```
internal sealed class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Role");

            BuildIndexes(builder);

            BuildProperties(builder);

            //TableSeed(builder);
        }

        private void BuildIndexes(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.HasIndex(m => m.Name).IsUnique();
        }

        private void BuildProperties(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasConversion(p => p.ToGuid(), p => new RoleId(p))
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                .HasConversion(p => p.ToString(), p => new RoleName(p))
                .HasMaxLength(60);
        }

        private void TableSeed(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
        {
            builder.HasData(
                new Role(RoleIdConstants.Admin, RoleNameConstants.Admin),
                new Role(RoleIdConstants.Manager, RoleNameConstants.Manager));
        }
    }
```

Every single property of my entities are ValueObjects, that`s why I'm using the the HasConversion.

Again, the first Migration works fine. If I delete my migrations now (after created the new entity) and create a Dev001 migration again, IT WORKS!!

It's just doesn`t work if I try to put 2 migrations in a row.

Thanks in advance guys.

**Further technical details**

- EF Core version: 3.1.5
- Database provider: Sql Server
- Target framework: ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Operating system: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 16.3

Comment: you didn't say anything about the update database.had you applied the first migration before adding second migration?

Comment: Hi Mohammed, yes I did. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21576#issuecomment-656813464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug on stable (what??) version of EFCore.

The link shows the answer:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21576